# What is needed to make smart phone application for website?

Tags: php, android, smartphone

Im too busy creating a website... but was wondering what part as a web developer i wud have to do? to make it easier for another developer to create a smart phone app for me. I dnt want to get my hands dirty with smart phone app development. Are there people out there who can code an app for me at a fair price? when logged in the site uses alot of jquery... so on old phones dnt work. please let me know as im naive at this. thanx

ps: the website is done in php/mysql on centos. `http://www.veepiz.com`

Comment: This forum is to solve programming problems, not to hire programmers. Consider using http://programmers.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I beg to differ, you seem to be *quite* naive at this. Voting to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually really easy. 
Try http://www.phonegap.com

It enables you to use your web development skills on smartphone development.
And best of all, if you have a mobile version of your page, then you can use the same template in your apps.
But the best part is: Cross-platform.
Ir runs on any major smartphone platform from iOs to WebOs.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should read http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/index.html.
Or have your Android developer to read this (when you find one) ;)